# Which IPTC fields for Common name and scientific name

Tags: metadata

I'm a nature photographer and want to know how to identify the plant or animal within an image.

eg
Common name: **Housefly**
Scientific name: ***Musca domestica***

Into which fields should the data in bold go?

Comment: That all depends on who you intend to be able to use that information. If for a party other than yourself, you need to ask them specifically which fields they require/prefer. If for yourself it doesn't really matter, just do it the same way consistently.

Answer (score 1):

If you're software supports it, technically I believe you would want to look at the [Darwin Core Taxon tags](https://dwc.tdwg.org/terms/#taxon).

For just general usage, `HierarchicalSubject` would bet a good place.  You can set up a hierarchy as simple as `Common Name|Housefly` and `Scientific Name|Musca domestica` or go full classification with `Animalia|Arthropoda|Insecta|Diptera|Schizophora|Muscidae|Musca|M. domestica` (`Kingdom|Phylum|Class|Order|Section|Family|Genus|Species`).  You could probably find a Controlled Vocabulary that would have such things already set up for you.